# How to exclude a column from SELECT query?

Tags: sql

I have 100 columns in a table and I want to list 99 columns except a particular one.

How to exclude that columns name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, 
     /* ...the list of columns 4-97, not shown in this example... */,
     column_98, column_99
   FROM table
```

There is no easier way to do this (possibly by design): you need to specifically list each of the columns you want to retrieve.

Although it's a hassle to write, this is actually a Good Thing: using `SELECT *` in production code is discouraged (both for performance and maintainability reasons) - see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).

Answer (score 8):

The [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29) relational database query language does allow a projection to be expressed in terms of the attributes to be removed using `ALL BUT` however there is no such equivalent syntax in SQL that allows you to do this. You need to explicitly list the specific ones that you want.

You could use a View if you commonly need this same set of columns.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

Theoretically, you might involve dynamic sql here - some procedure will loop through all columns of your table (like, `all_tabs_columns` dictionary view in Oracle lists all columns of all tables), and form up you a query of `select c1, c2 c3 ... c99 from tab`, but I strongly discourage you of doing this. Will save you several lines of code, but make it hard to maintain. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
DROP TABLE #MY_TEMP_TABLE

CREATE TABLE #MY_TEMP_TABLE
(
    Column_1        int             NULL,
    Column_2        varchar(10)     NULL,
    Column_3        datetime        NULL
)

INSERT INTO #MY_TEMP_TABLE(Column_1, Column_2, Column_3)
        SELECT  1, 'a', GETDATE()
UNION   SELECT  2, 'b', GETDATE()
UNION   SELECT  3, 'c', GETDATE()
UNION   SELECT  4, 'd', GETDATE()

DECLARE @dSQL nvarchar(1000)

SELECT  @dSQL = 'SELECT TOP 10 '

SELECT  @dSQL = @dSQL + LEFT(nst.ColumnList, LEN(nst.ColumnList)-1) --AS 'List'
FROM    (SELECT  so.id
        FROM    TEMPDB..SYSOBJECTS so
        WHERE   so.name LIKE '#MY_TEMP_TABLE%'
        AND     so.type = 'u') so
CROSS APPLY (SELECT sc.Name + ', '
            FROM    TEMPDB..SYSCOLUMNS sc
            WHERE   sc.id = so.id
            AND     sc.colid <> 3
            FOR XML PATH('')) nst
            (ColumnList)

SELECT  @dSQL = @dSQL + ' FROM #MY_TEMP_TABLE'

EXEC sp_executesql @dSQL
```

Answer (score 1):

Much faster query solution! In bold text, add your table name and column name to be remove. You can add as many fields as you want to remove.

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)=(SELECT string_agg(COLUMN_NAME,',') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='YOURTABLENAME'

AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('REMOVEDCOLOUMN',.........))

SET @query ='select '+@query+' FROM YOURTABLENAME' EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Much faster query solution as temp table will take time and memory.

Answer (score -1):

It's little touches like this that make BiqQuery much more pleasant to use than SSMS.

You can simply use

```sql
select * except (columnToRemove,....) from table
```