# Exclude foreign keys from sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got some sql joining a few tables together

```
SELECT contact.contact_id,
        form1.*,
        form2.*
FROM contact
INNER JOIN form1
ON contact.contact_id = form1.contact_id
INNER JOIN form2
ON contact_contact_id = form2.contact_id
```

I want to avoid repeating the 'contact_id' column in my output without having to write every field name in the table (ie I want to keep using `form1.*` and `form2.*` as this will make the report much easier to maintain - fields are liable to change). Is this possible? I'm using Postgres.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650689/sql-exclude-a-column-from-select-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way is "Dont use *". You need to explicitely type out the required column. This is a good practice when you use JOINs. If the columns are too many, make use of the result

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_name='your table' and column_name<>'contact_id'
```

Comment: When you say 'make use of the result' are you thinking programmatically or are you talking about cutting and pasting?

Answer (score 1):

If contact_id is the only column name that the tables share, you can use 'natural join' to join the tables and you will end up with only one copy of the joining column.

Comment: lead me to 'USING' instead of 'NATURAL'. But both statments seem to require 'SELECT * FROM' - I can't specify some columsn then let 'NATURAL' handle the rest.